# Possible bug with FindGeoLocation

Tags: geographics

I am using a simple call,

```
FindGeoLocation["NP20 5PB"],
```

whose output is

```
GeoPosition[{51.5982, -3.00016}],
```

indicating that the lat-long data for this postcode exists. However, when embedded in a Do loop that cycles through many thousands postcodes this particular call gave an error. After cleaning up the escape characters the error is this:

```
Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 1 in FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[Missing[RetrievalFailure]]]
```

I include the stack trace as a screenshot since the InputForm is unreadable:

[image: Stack Trace]

I searched "conopen" and found [this post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1215731) about something completely different that was apparently a bug in Mathematica. I have no idea whether my problem is also a bug but it seems like a possibility. I can restart the loop whenever I encounter this problem, and have done so already a few times. So this (possible) bug is not a show-stopper, but it is annoying and is slowing me down.

Not sure if I am following the right protocol posting this issue here. If it's not a bug and I am doing something stupid please let me know, thank you.

Comment: `FindGeoLocation` uses the network to query a Nominatim instance that Wolfram run. If you hit it too hard, it will fail to return data and cause this type of issue. Consider adding a wait time in your loop so that you don't hit the server with thousands of requests at the same time.

Comment: Please read [tag:bugs] on how to use this tag.

Comment: Thank you @CarlLange, that makes sense, I will try that.

Comment: Sorry @Szabolcs, I will keep that in mind.